# Very Dynamic & animated Listview with Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am facing these complex(for me) architecture situation.

In my app I have a dynamic vote listview. Its like every items in the view have vote and list in ascending order. But this list's item's vote can change through my socket connection triggering.  Second vote can be First or Third can be Second. And I wanna make this changing situation with smooth animate.

How can I control the UI things. Should I use StreamBuilder->ListViewBuilder. But in this situation how can I control and animate rank changing.